# Android SQLIte No Such Table Error - On Click

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, runtime-error

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a database for a monthly assessment form as part of my, it will be the second table of my application first being login details.

I followed the same format but am getting "NO SUCH TABLE" followed by my variable name.

I was hoping this issue had been seen before and how it could be eradicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the old application on your phone completely and run your project again. This error is happening because the `onCreate()` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` derived class is called only once. For it to be called again, either you derive another custom class from `SQLiteOpenHelper` and define your second table there, or you uninstall the old APK and re-run the project from the IDE. When you run it again, both tables will be created.

Comment: @Zygotelnit Hi and thanks for the rapid response. I am however still getting the error. I have updated the question above to reflect the error log showing but I have tried uninstalling the apk to device but unfortunately it does not seem to be creating the table

Comment: i will get back to you in a few minutes :)

Comment: Very kind @Zygotelnit :)

Comment: @Zygotelnit The error was in my DatabaseHelper.java which I did not post! In the public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) I did not state the new database was to be created! Thanks for your input!

Comment: You're welcome ... I believe you got to see first hand that when working with SQLite tables which are all defined in the same `onCreate()`, the old APK should be deleted when a new table is added.

Answer (score 0):

Make database like this :

```
public class Data_Base extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String dbname = "suri29";
    public static final Integer dbversion = 1;
    public static final String dbtable = "user";
    public static final String name = "username";
    public static final String column_id = "_id";

    public Data_Base(Context context) {
        super(context, dbname, null, dbversion);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table " + dbtable + " (" + column_id
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, username text not null)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVesion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + dbtable);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging deeper into you code, I have some advices for you that going to make you avoid tons of mistakes:

1)Use `SQLite Database Helper` for creating, inserting, deleting you data from the database...Follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

2)Rewriting your columns name in each query is a very bad practice. Initialize them at the beginning of your class as `final static string` and use this variable whenever you need it.

```
private final static String COL_COMMENTS = "COMMENTS";
```

3)`Try and catch` all your database transactions with logging to avoid crashes.

```
try{
  //Database transaction
 }
 catch(Exception e){
  e.printstacktrace();
 }
```

4)Uninstall the application and install it again after adding any new table.